# xna + wcf runs very slow - but only when fullsceen ! (going insane ?)

Tags: wcf, xna

I have an XNA application that communicates with another process (on the same computer) using WCF.
On each Update cycle, the XNA will get data from the other process.

The XNA runs fine when in a window (over 60fps),
but if I try to run it fullscreen, I'm getting less than 1fps.
This does not happen if I turn off the WCF.

Why would fullscreen affect it like that ?
Any ideas ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a long shot, providing that there's not much details, but it looks to me you have some thread starvation issues, possibly caused by page flip / buffer swap waiting for something? (What OS are you using, how many cores)

You should try using the profiler and analyzing the code to see where is the critical secion.

For a quick fix, try using Thread.Sleep(1), or switching to Async calls for your WCF service.

Comment: Running on Win7 64bit with a two core CPU. What really kills me is that the application runs fine when not fullscreen. The code is identical. I will try the sleep trick.